# choose the best variable after comparing them

Tags: c++, optimization, compare

Surely the question was asked but I didn't know how to formulate my research to get relevant results.

In my problem, I have a point A and several other points B,C... on a plane.
I want to compare the distances between A-B, A-C, ... and return the closest point for example B.

Except that my way is not very optimized maybe you have better ideas.

here is a small piece of my code that summarizes what I said here is a small piece of my code that summarizes what I said and I replaced the points that are two dimensional vectors by simple int to simplify the explanation.

```
int A(5);
int B(7);
int C(-3);
int D(9);

int i(1);
int best_dist = A-B;

if((A-C) < best_dist)
{
 best_dist = A-C;
 i = 2;
}

if((A-D) < best_dist)
{
 best_dist = A-D;
 i = 3;
}

switch(i){
 case 1:
    return B;
    break;
 case 2:
    return C;
    break;
 case 3:
    return D;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Can you put them in an array of a vector? That would allow iteration over them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the numbers (/coordinates) into a container (say `std::array`) and use `std::min_element` to find the member from which the "from" point (`A`, in your example) has the smallest absolute distance. E.g.:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::min_element
#include <array>
#include <cmath>     // std::abs
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  constexpr int from{5};
  constexpr std::array<int, 3> candidates{7, -3, 9};

  // consider using an != end() check on the resulting
  // iterator if you do not know the container to be non-empty.
  int const closest_point_on_plane = *std::min_element(
      candidates.begin(), candidates.end(), [](int lhs, int rhs) {
        return std::abs(from - lhs) < std::abs(from - rhs);
      });

  std::cout << closest_point_on_plane; // 7
}
```

For your actual use case of a plane, you will have to replace the

```
std::abs(from_point_on_line - to_point_on_line)
```

distance-on-a-line metric used in the compare lambda with an appropriate

```
distance(from_point_on_plane, to_point_on_plane)
```

distance-on-a-plane metric.

Comment: OP has problem in 2D, and simplified example to 1D, so `std::abs(from - lhs)` has to be replaced by "custom" `distance(from, lhs)` (they are [several ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) which may lead to different results).